# Bash: nested for loop + middle loop contains two arrays?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, sh

Maybe I'm over-thinking this but here's my desired output:

```
one four seven 
one five eight
one six nine
two four seven
two five eight
two six nine
three four seven
three five eight
three six nine
```

Here's what I started. I got to the second for loop and totally lost my mind trying to find the solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a aaa=("four" "five" "six")
declare -a bbb=("one" "two" "three")
declare -a ccc=("seven" "eight" "nine")


for bs in ${bbb[@]}; do
  for as in ${aaa[@]}, cs in ${ccc[@]}; do
    echo "$bs" "$as" "$cs"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one `in` in a `for` clause.

If you need to iterate two arrays simultaneously, iterate over their indices:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a aaa=("four" "five" "six")
declare -a bbb=("one" "two" "three")
declare -a ccc=("seven" "eight" "nine")

for b in "${bbb[@]}" ; do
    for i in "${!aaa[@]}" ; do  # or ccc
        echo "$b" "${aaa[i]}" "${ccc[i]}"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my original question to better address my problem. I over-simplified the issue originally. Thanks for your help though. I would be grateful if you tried to solve this again.

Comment: @zewiblzd: Updated. Next time, please ask a new question if it's significantly different to the original one.